# Actionbar, Toolbar, activity inheritance

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-fragments, android-toolbar

My activities extend from a generic base activity, where I declare and initialize public variables like `context` of type Context, `activity` of type Activity and mActionBar of type `ActionBar`.

So this avoids redundant initialization code in all my app's activities.

But with the advent of `Toolbar`, I am a little confused on how to do this. Toolbar is not like ActionBar and replaces it, but also extends it.

The ActionBar is a view object that is always available for retrieval, by ActionBar activity, and it sits above the views that are created. This is not declared in layout XML anywhere.

But Toolbar is declared only in layout XML, so I have to include it in each and every layout I create, or else I will not be able to access the Toolbar object.

I typically use `setContentView(R.layout.mylayout)` in the `onCreate` method of each individual activity. And then I have to initialize my Toolbar object after that using `findViewById`. Therefore I can't put this code in my BaseActivity's onCreate function because the `setContentView` wouldn't have been initialized yet.

Even if I created Toolbar programmatically with it's constructor, and attempted to add the view to the top of the hierarchy, I would still have to do this on a layout by layout, and activity by activity basis, because some layouts are RelativeLayout's as the root object, and others are different. So these will still have separate code considerations.

The reason I am curious about a good way for my activities to inherit Toolbar, is because it is a complete nightmare for Google to suddenly require Android 4.0-4.4 devices to use the v7 compatibility pack, replace the actionbar completely with the Toolbar object, use v4 compatibility pack fragments instead of native ones, all to use the latest design paradigms.

Comment: "hey check out v21 ! but your v17 device needs to use v4 objects to check it out"

Comment: You could set the content View, with the Toolbar, in the base Activity class, and inflate the subclasses' Views into a container ViewGroup in the base layout.

Comment: @MikeM. I feel like this will be a problem. I also use the NavigationDrawer's DrawerLayout, which comes in front of the ToolBar, and will need to be a root element. In other cases I also use other libraries that rely on being a root element

Comment: In that case, you could create a separate layout for the Toolbar and inflate and initialize it in the base's `onCreate()` method, but don't add it to the on-screen layout until after the subclass calls `setContentView()`.

Comment: @MikeM. that isn't much different than what I currently have, but that's fine, thanks.

Comment: @CQM did you ever find a solution? I am facing pretty much the same problem: Navigation Drawer + an Activity hierarchy in the context of the new ToolBar with Material Design. 
If so, with a globally accessible toolBar, would each Activity share the same reference of the tool bar? I'm concerned that the Activities would overwrite each other's attributes when they modify the tool bar. For example, if Activity A did `toolBar.setTitle("titleA")`, would it override Activity B's title?

Comment: @kip2 I did figure out a solution, my base activity has a toolbar variable, but all my sub activities have to re-declare it, as it is now duplicated in all of my XML layouts. One activity does not override another activity's use of the Toolbar object

Comment: @CQM, in that [sad] case, there's really no point having a `protected ToolBar mToolBar` that would be inherited by all sub activities. It's rather annoying to have to re-declare the toolbar layout in every activity (even with use of the <include> paradigm), for me it just negates the whole objective of having an app-wide reusable component. I can appreciate that ToolBar offers more flexibility, but ActionBar just worked and Google could've done better here.

Comment: @chris-banes what do you think regarding this issue? I still think ToolBar should be accessible in all inheriting classes. Contrary to your comment in another thread (https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/#comment-1642002002), I haven't seen any other alternative but to re-instantiate the toolbar in each activity that wants to show it

Comment: Did any one find a solution here? I am having the same problem in inheriting the Toolbar in my child activities.

Answer (score 4):

this is my implementation. Hope it helps someone.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    protected boolean useToolbar() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, null);
        configureToolbar(view);
        super.setContentView(view);
    }

    private void configureToolbar(View view) {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            if (useToolbar()) {
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            } else {
                toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From here on you just extend BaseActivity. If you don't want a toolbar you will have to override the useToolbar().

Don't forget to add in activity.xml at the top

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</merge>
```